# Python: Cannot put json format(dict) values into a list

Tags: python, json, list, for-loop, if-statement

I tried to extract a set of date values from a json input. And when i finished the extraction of `F_Date` , it was correct.

```
2020-05-20T00:00:00
2020-05-18T00:00:00
2020-05-15T00:00:00
2020-05-13T00:00:00
```

I set a list to contain the values, so I wanna use the index of list like `List[0]`to take the first value in the list or the other value in the list for further purpose. However, it failed. It gave me a column of first charactor. If I try `List[1]`, ofc it gave me a column of `0` instead of `2020-05-18T00:00:00`,which is what exactly I want to have. Any Idea what's wrong with my code? I fell confused to what type `F_Date` is now, it is not a list?

Thanks in advance.

```
F_Date = []
for cell in json["Cells"]:
    if cell["ColumnName"] == "T":
        if cell["RowIndex"] + 1 > 9:
            F_Date = cell["DisplayValue"]
            print(F_Date[0])


output:
2
2
2
2
```

Json:

```
json =    {
            "SheetName": "price",
            "SheetIndex": 4,
            "Cells": [
                {
                    "ColumnName": "T",
                    "RowName": "10",
                    "Address": "T10",
                    "ColumnIndex": 19,
                    "RowIndex": 9,
                    "Value": "2020-05-20T00:00:00",
                    "DisplayValue": "2020-05-20T00:00:00",
                    "ValueType": "Date"
                },
                {
                    "ColumnName": "U",
                    "RowName": "10",
                    "Address": "U10",
                    "ColumnIndex": 20,
                    "RowIndex": 9,
                    "Value": 2.75,
                    "DisplayValue": 2.75,
                    "ValueType": "Numeric"
                },
                {
                    "ColumnName": "V",
                    "RowName": "10",
                    "Address": "V10",
                    "ColumnIndex": 21,
                    "RowIndex": 9,
                    "Value": 2.15,
                    "DisplayValue": 2.15,
                    "ValueType": "Numeric"
                },
                {
                    "ColumnName": "T",
                    "RowName": "11",
                    "Address": "T11",
                    "ColumnIndex": 19,
                    "RowIndex": 10,
                    "Value": "2020-05-18T00:00:00",
                    "DisplayValue": "2020-05-18T00:00:00",
                    "ValueType": "Date"
                },
                {
                    "ColumnName": "U",
                    "RowName": "11",
                    "Address": "U11",
                    "ColumnIndex": 20,
                    "RowIndex": 10,
                    "Value": 2.75,
                    "DisplayValue": 2.75,
                    "ValueType": "Numeric"
                },
                {
                    "ColumnName": "V",
                    "RowName": "11",
                    "Address": "V11",
                    "ColumnIndex": 21,
                    "RowIndex": 10,
                    "Value": 2.15,
                    "DisplayValue": 2.15,
                    "ValueType": "Numeric"
                },
                {
                    "ColumnName": "T",
                    "RowName": "12",
                    "Address": "T12",
                    "ColumnIndex": 19,
                    "RowIndex": 11,
                    "Value": "2020-05-15T00:00:00",
                    "DisplayValue": "2020-05-15T00:00:00",
                    "ValueType": "Date"
                },
                {
                    "ColumnName": "U",
                    "RowName": "12",
                    "Address": "U12",
                    "ColumnIndex": 20,
                    "RowIndex": 11,
                    "Value": 2.75,
                    "DisplayValue": 2.75,
                    "ValueType": "Numeric"
                },
                {
                    "ColumnName": "V",
                    "RowName": "12",
                    "Address": "V12",
                    "ColumnIndex": 21,
                    "RowIndex": 11,
                    "Value": 2.15,
                    "DisplayValue": 2.15,
                    "ValueType": "Numeric"
                },
                {
                    "ColumnName": "T",
                    "RowName": "13",
                    "Address": "T13",
                    "ColumnIndex": 19,
                    "RowIndex": 12,
                    "Value": "2020-05-13T00:00:00",
                    "DisplayValue": "2020-05-13T00:00:00",
                    "ValueType": "Date"
                }
        ]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is print F_Date instead of F_Date[0] which only prints the first Character as a String can be interpreted as a list of Characters and you are printing the index 0.

```
print(F_Date)
```

If you are confused to what F_Date is, F_Date is your Date String as it is the value to the key in the Dictonary you get.

```
F_Date = []
for cell in json["Cells"]:
    if cell["ColumnName"] == "T":
        if cell["RowIndex"] + 1 > 9:
            F_Date = cell["DisplayValue"] # Here you set F_Date to the value 
            print(F_Date[0])
```

i think what you ment to do is this

```
F_Date = []
for cell in json["Cells"]:
    if cell["ColumnName"] == "T":
        if cell["RowIndex"] + 1 > 9:
            F_Date.append(cell["DisplayValue"]) 
            print(cell["DisplayValue"])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. May I ask a further silly question, I set the empty F_Date in list format at first, why `F_Date = cell["DisplayValue"]` was just set F_Date to the value instead of putting the value in a list?  I mean if I don't use append function, the F_Date would not be a list format with values forever?

Comment: @Andersen the thing is python doesnt have fixed variable types so a single variabel can be list, double, str, int, dict or whatever in the course of a program. even though you set F_Date as an empty list at the start you are overwriting it in every iteration. F_Date = newVal. But this is the same in other programming languages. IF you dont use append it wont work.